# Open Google Calendar Via Sheets and Allow user to create Entry with info from Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-calendar-api

I have a sheet and I want the user to enter some details like a Name and Location.  I then want to to press a button which will launch Google Calendar and allow them to create a entry that will add the Name and Location details and then send the Date and Time of the event back to sheets.

I have looked everywhere for code for this but can only find creating an event in the calendar if the date and time are set in the sheet already.

Is this even possible?

Comment: You probably would do better to have the user open a FORM (not a calendar) that has all the input fields one would need. Then capture the form responses and push them back to sheets, and possibly update a calendar. Having outside users directly update your calendar is probably a bad approach.

Comment: Look at this: [Good Events Planner](https://gsuite.google.com/marketplace/app/good_events_planner/70860658795)